# What in the world is going on with the Ring of Ki Mastery?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, equipment, designer-reasons

I was looking over building an [unchained monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained/) for a campaign I'm going to be starting, and I wanted to reduce the price of some of the [Ki Powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained/#TOC-Ki-Power-Su-). Looking for a way to do that brought me to the [Ring of Ki Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-ki-mastery/) and looking over it, I have a few questions.

1) Why is the price so weird? The crafting cost is 3,420, but the purchasing cost is 10,000. Isn't the crafting cost supposed to be half the buy cost in most instances? And if this is supposed to be an exception, what's changing the price?

2) Does the ring have a cap on how much Ki you can store in it? I've seen people argue both that it's unlimited thanks to the "at least 2 ki" text, and others say that it caps at 2. So...?

3) Finally, when it says, "the wearer reduces the number of ki points needed to use a ninja trick or ki ability by 1 (minimum 1 ki point)." how do I determine what ability it reduces? All of them? One that's chosen when it's first built? The one I decide when I first put ki in?

I'm not looking for a RAW interpretation, because at least according to the RAW I can find it's just wonky (I even looked through the "Ask James Jacobs" thread and still didn't find anything). But if there's some hidden errata or developer notes I'm missing, those would be highly appreciated.

This could either be a must-have for ki users or a complete waste of ink to even print in the first place, so what is going on with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) No dev commentary nor errata seems to address the weird price.  It is the same price as the similar-but-weaker [*Ring of Grit Mastery*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-grit-mastery/), and that is the only other item with that price, so that might have something to do with it.  It's especially weird that the better ring is so much cheaper to create, but the grit one does give you access to a nonaction action, and those are usually pretty expensive.

2) It stores as much as you want, but you have to have the ki to fill it, and you have to have the ring to use it.  That's the broken part, because normally your ki is capped at a certain number but now it's uncapped and you can build it up over time.

Fortunately, even having infinite ki wouldn't actually be a big problem in most cases; just like spells ordinarily require a very limited resource (spell slots) to use, but items can bypass that requirement, allowing you to use them at will, so too does infinite ki alter the class balance in question.  It *is* a must-have for ki users, basically, but it's not actually going to make them super powerful or anything, especially since the ring's not actually infinite (If it was, at 7th level the monk would have effectively infinite instant hit point regeneration, which would be pretty cool/unique, but even that's not *that* big a deal by level 9 or so).

If we accept that the item is largely based off of the *Ring of Grit Mastery*, this overflow mechanic is probably intentional.  The grit ring functions more or less identically to the ki ring, except the the two bonuses granted are different, the putting points in mechanism has been changed from a free action 2/day to unlimited swift actions, and the cap has been removed.  As you note, the 'at least 2' text also independently reinforces the idea that the cap removal (or non-inclusion, if the Ki ring is not based off the Grit one) is intentional.

3) All of them, but to a minimum of 1.

Comment: There's no way it's unlimited. Pathfinder never includes mechanics like that. Consider that this is PFS legal, and in PFS you have unlimited time between adventures. If this really worked, then you actually would have infinite ki, which would in fact give you infinite HP.